# Drupal 7, save new node while editing old

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My need is to change behavior of edit form, for several content types.

The objective is:
-After update button has been pressed, don't update the node but create a new one with values from old node. I could do that by passing old node's fields values to "/node/add/my_content" form but this require a lot of work (the forms are quite complicated) and on edit page i have already all values ready in my fields.

So i already tried hook_form_alter

```
function mymodule_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'my_not_update_form':
      $node = $form_state['node'];
      if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
      // This is a new node.
      }
      else {
        $new_node = new StdClass();
        $new_node->type = 'my_not_update_form';
        node_object_prepare($new_node);
        $new_node->uid = $user->uid;
        $new_node->language = 'und';
        $new_node->title = NULL;

        $form['vid']['#value'] = NULL;
        $form['nid']['#value'] = NULL;
        $form['created']['#value'] = $new_node->created;
        $form['changed']['#default_value'] = NULL;

        $form['#node'] = $new_node;
        $form['#entity'] = $new_node;
        $form_state['node'] = $new_node;
        $form_state['build_info']['args'][0] = $new_node;
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

So with the above code i'm able to create a new node but the "create date" parameter always stay the same as create date parameter of an old node and none of the above line can solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an entirely new node when you submit edits to an existing node, then you want to use [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x), which allows you to set any property of the node object before it's saved to the database.

In this example unsetting the `nid` and `vid`, and explicitly setting the `is_new` property will achieve this:

```
function my_module_node_presave($node) {
  unset($node->nid);
  unset($node->vid);
  $node->is_new = TRUE;
}
```

This will leave the existing node untouched and unedited, and will instead create an entirely new node.

Comment: That's not the point of my problem. I'm not creating a new node by regular way. I'm updating node and want to overwrite $form and $form_state variables to cheat node_form_submit() that this function will think that data which is going to be save is new node not the old one.

Comment: I have made a change to the code so that it hopefully addresses your comment.

Answer (score 0):

So to fully change the behavior of form update i give up on hook_form_alter() and instead i used hook_node_presave

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if($node->is_new == FALSE || isset($node->nid)) {
    unset($node->nid);
    unset($node->vid);
    unset($node->vuuid);
    $node -> created = time();
    $node -> timestamp = time();
    $node-> is_new = TRUE;
    $node -> changed = time();
    unset($node->revision_timestamp);
    unset($node->num_revisions);
    unset($node->current_revision_id);
    unset($node->is_current);
    unset($node->is_pending);
    unset($node->revision_moderation);
    unset($node->date);
    unset($node->vuuid);
    unset($node->data);
  }
}
```